# Put image between 2 div with z-index

Tags: css, z-index

I try to position image between .previewSlide div and .PreviewArrowUl with z-index.

The z-index of .previewSlide is 1, the .PreviewArrowUl is 5 and my img is 20 but PreviewArrowUl is over the img.

```
.previewSlide {
    height: 110px;
    background-color: #484848;
    z-index: 1;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}

.PreviewArrowUl {
    position: absolute;
    background: #9b9b9b;
    height: 125px;
    width: 185px !important;
    z-index: 5;
    left: 185px;
    top: 0px;
    background-color: #9b9b9b;
}

.previewSlide ul li img {
    width: 155px;
    height: 85px;
    float: left;
    z-index: 20;
    position: relative;
}
```

You can check my example [in this JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wx4yzxwt/).

Anyone have an idea why my image is under the PreviewArrowUl ?

Comment: col-lg-10 ? (I guess bootstrap, don't forget to add it to your fiddle)

Comment: Updated your fiddle with the code you posted in the question. It's working fine: https://jsfiddle.net/wx4yzxwt/1/

Comment: @Yobogs That "updated" fiddle doesn't have the HTML for `.PreviewArrowUl`...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`absolute`ly positioned elements shall always overlap the `static`ally positioned element (default).

Here the explanation...

The precedence of `z-index` is as follows

1. canvas (where the element is drawn / parents drawable area)
2. bg images
3. z-index: -1
4. default (0)
5. z-index: 1+

So when you give any child element a z-index of -1, it won't go below the parents background because of the parents precedence. **Also z-index only works on positioned elements**. So assigning the z-index to an element without any position assigned (even though defaults to `static`) wont have any effect on its `position in stack` .

Comment: Gawd, atleast let me complete my answer before downvoting!!